# Problem aggregate elasticsearch return result buckets greater than 10k objects

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate result from elasticsearch. But when I read document about max_size_query of elasticsearch it is not greater than 10k objects. So, is this issue will impact to my result aggrerate when size of butkets return greater than 10k result?

Comment: which aggregation are you using ?

Comment: I try to aggregate from this document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html